# Why am I losing messages when I use ReceiveAndDelete?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

```
yield return new ServiceInstanceListener(context => new ServiceBusQueueCommunicationListener(
                      new Handler(logAction, context)
                          , context
                          , serviceBusReceiveConnectionString: Config.connectionString
                          , serviceBusQueueName: Config.QueueName
                          , requireSessions: true)
        {

            MaxConcurrentSessions = 1000,
            ReceiveMode = ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete,
            LogAction = logAction,               
            MessagePrefetchCount = 10
        }, "StatelessService-ServiceBusQueueListener");
```

the key value of losing messages is "MessagePrefetchCount":
i have 100 messages in the queue ,when this code runs ,it will consume them all but i will receive only 10 messages.
if i change "MessagePrefetchCount" to be 50 then i will receive only 2 messages and all rest messages will be consumed but not received.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Receive-and-Delete mode is used to receive the messages the broker considers all messages it sends to the receiving client as settled when sent. That means that the message is considered consumed as soon as the broker has put it onto the wire. If the message transfer fails, the message is lost.

Check for the [message expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration) and other reasons due to which the messages might have been lost.